# Correct pattern for exposing available actions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvvm, command-pattern

I have an class which can perform many analytics on a given object and return back sets of results:

```
public class AnalyserClass
{
    private SomeObject _someObject;

    public AnalyserClass(SomeObject someobject)
    {
        _someObject = someobject;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Result> DoA
    {
        //checks A on someObject and returns some results
    }

    public IEnumerable<Result> DoB
    {
        //checks B on someObject and returns some results
    }

    //etc

}

public class Result
{
    //various properties with result information
}

public class SomeObject
{
    //this is the object which is analysed
}
```

I would like to expose these actions (DoA, DoB etc) in a CheckedListBox in a WinForm. The user would then tick the actions s/he wants performed and would then click on a Run button.

I would ideally like exposing the actions to be dynamic - so, if I develop a new action within my AnalyserClass, it will automatically show up and be executable from the WinForm without any code changes anywhere else.

I am a fairly new C# programmer. I have been researching how best to structure this and I have become a little bit confused between various patterns and which one would be most appropriate to use.

First of all I read up on the MVVM pattern, but this seems to be more complicated than is required here and I don't understand what the Model would be.

Then I looked at the Command pattern. But from what I understand, I would have to create a class wrapper for every single action (there are a lots) which would be quite time consuming and seem to be a bit cumbersome (change code in multiple places, so not 'dynamic'). I also don't understand how I could build the list of checkboxes from the command classes. This does seem to be the most appropriate pattern that I could find, but I am uncertain about it because of my lack of experience.

Your guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: `I would ideally like exposing the actions to be dynamic` You're going to need reflection to locate all the available actions then.  In the end you'll need an object that looks like `List<Func<IEnumerable<Result>>` to expose to the user.

Comment: I considered having an enum which is mapped to each action so I could easily reflect that to build the checkbox list. Then I could add a Run() method to my analyser class which takes an enum (flags) or list of enums which could be called from the Run button on the form. But again I'm really unsure if this is the correct thing to do. Am I being 'greedy' in hoping the actions are dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not choose Reflection here, because it makes the things unnecessary complicated.

Furthermore, with your current approach, you would need to extend your `AnalyserClass` with new functionality every time you need a new analyzer tool, and that:

- breaks the "open-closed" principle of SOLID,
- breaks the "single responsibility" principle of SOLID,
- makes your class too large and pretty unmaintainable.

I would introduce in your `AnalyserClass` a collection of supported actions:

```
class AnalyserClass
{
    public IEnumerable<IAnalyzer> Analyzers { get; private set; }
}
```

...where the `IAnalyzer` interface describes your actions:

```
interface IAnalyzer
{
    string Description { get; }         // this is what user will see as the action name
    Result Perform(SomeObject input);
}
```

Then you can implement the `IAnalyzer` in various classes as needed, even in different modules etc.

The only open point would be - how to add all the `IAnalyzer` instances into your `AnalyzerClass.Analyzers` collection?

Well:

- you can use a DI framework (e.g. MEF) and let it discover all the things automatically,
- you can inject them manually via DI,
- you can use Reflection and scan the types manually,
- you can add them manually e.g. in the constructor of the `AnalyzerClass` (simple but not recommended)
- and so on...

Comment: This answer looks great. I understand I will use the description properties to fill out my checked listbox, but when I am doing that how do I link the checkbox to the class itself ? Do I just use the Tag property?

Comment: It would be very easy with MVVM; however, I'm not sure how to implement MVVM in WinForms. In WPF, it would be done automatically by the Data Binding Engine (using view-models). I think there are Data Bindings in WinForms too, but unfortunately I'm not aware of how they are working.